# Why can't I use the multiplication rule here?

Tags: combinatorics

## Problem

A group consists of 4 girls and 7 boys. In how many ways can a team of 5 members be selected if the team has at least one boy and one girl?

## Incorrect solution

No. of ways you can select 1 boy: $^7C_{1} = 7$

No. of ways you can select 1 girl: $^4C_{1} = 4$

No. of ways you can select 3 from the remaining $6+3=9$ members: $^9C_{3} = 84$

Therefore: No. of ways you can build the team: $7 \times 4 \times 84 = 2352$

Note: this is obviously wrong because $2352 >$ $^{11}C_{5} = 462$

## What I need help with

Why is the application of the multiplication rule failing here?

Comment: You are counting each team more than once.

Comment: Hmm, I see that now but it would be great to understand how I am over counting the teams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider, for instance, a team with members A, B, C, D, and E, where A, B, and C are girls and D and E are boys.  Your method of counting actually counts this team $6$ different times:

- We could pick D as our boy, then pick A as our girl, then pick B, C, and E as the last three team members.
- We could pick D as our boy, then pick B as our girl, then pick A, C, and E as the last three team members.
- etc.

The team is counted $6$ times in total since there are $2$ boys we might pick first and $3$ girls we might pick second.

More generally, your method counts every team multiple times.  You are actually counting the number of ways to form a team with a *chosen* boy member and a *chosen* girl member, and you can choose a boy and a girl member from a single team in multiple ways.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks!